# How to track the number of loops in AVAudioFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am making an audio player in my iOS project.
I setup the `play(audioOfUrl:URL, for times:Int)`method by passing the name of the url and how many times the audio file will be play as following:

```
func play(audioOfUrl:URL, for times:Int) {

    let urlPath = audioOfUrl
    loopsLeftOver = times
    do {

        let audio = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: urlPath)
        audioPlayer = audio
        audio.play()
        audio.numberOfLoops = times - 1


    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

there will be a `pause()` and `resume()` as well, What I need to do is keep track of how many loops the audio player leftover.
For example, if I call the play method like this:

```
play(audioOfUrl:audioUrl, for times:5)
```

I need to keep eyes on the times leftover as the audio player running.

I try to use the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` method, but it is not working, how to keep eyes on the audio.numberOfLoops? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe for AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime notification and count how many times the handler of this notification has been called.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)),
                            name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                            object: audioPlayer.currentItem)
```